# Activity_ is not abstract and does not override abstract method findViewById(int) in HasViews

Tags: android, annotations, stripe-payments

I'm using androidannotations

```
annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

My project was working correctly, but when i have added stripe gradle entry

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.0'
```

then facing this issue

```
Activity_ is not abstract and does not override abstract method findViewById(int) in HasViews
```

Comment: What version of Android Annotations are you using? And what is your compile SDK version?

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0

Comment: And the compileSdkVersion for your project?

Comment: I have tried with 26.0.2

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation for Android 26](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#fvbi-signature), the signature for the `findViewById` method was changed as follows:

> All instances of the findViewById() method now return  T instead of View

This broke Android Annotations at the time, but the issue was quickly addressed in version 4.3.1 - see the [release notes](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/ReleaseNotes#431-).

Basically, if you're compiling for Android 26 or above, you need to switch to at least version 4.3.1 of Android Annotations.

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear. What I meant was, regardless of whether you're compiling for API 26 or 27, you need to use at least version 4.3.1 of Android Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This AndroidAnnotations issue is tracking the problem:
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2001

Google changed the signature of thier findViewById in Android O, and AndroidAnnotations does not support Android O due to this change

Comment: That issue has been resolved and closed - it seems that androidannotations has supported Android Oreo since version 4.3.1.

Comment: never stable any version always getting issue very stuck